# Cayley transformation of a skew-symmetric matrix is orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

If $S$ is skew-symmetric ($S^{T} = -S$), how do I show that $Q$ is orthogonal where

$$Q = (I + S)(I - S)^{-1}$$ which is the Cayley transformation of $S$.

Answer (score 7):

Just compute

$$QQ^T=(I+S)(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)^{-1}(I-S)$$
and since $(I+S)=-(I-S)+2I$ commutes with $(I-S)^{-1}$ then the result follows easily.

**Remarks**

1. We used the result $(A^{-1})^T=(A^T)^{-1}$
2. Prove for a skew-symmetric matrix S that $\pm1$ are not eigenvalues for it so that the inverse of $(S-I)$ and $(S+I)$ exist.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I got to that  part, but I couldn't turn $QQ^{T}$ into $I$. COuld you give more explanation?

Comment: Just commute $(I+S)$ and $(I-S)^{-1}$.

Comment: how do you show that $(I + S)(I - S)^{-1} = (I - S)^{-1}(I + S)$?
That's what I don't get.

Comment: As I explained in my answer $(I+S)=-(I-S)+2I$ and both $(I-S)$ and $I$ commute with $(I-S)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

First we show that Q can also be written as:

$$Q=(I-S)^{-1}(I+S).-------(*)$$

Since, $I+S=-(I-S)+2I$

$(I+S)(I-S)^{-1}=(-(I-S)+2I)(I-S)^{-1}=-I+2(I-S)^{-1}=(I-S)^{-1}(-(I-S)+2I)=(I-S)^{-1}(I+S).$

Now, since $S$ is skew  symmetric, $S^{T}=-S.$ Hence,

$Q^{T}=[(I+S)(I-S)^{-1}]^{T}=(I-S^{T})^{-1}(I+S^{T})=(I+S)^{-1}(I-S).$

Hence, $QQ^{T}=(I+S)(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)^{-1}(I-S)=(I-S)^{-1}(I+S)(I+S)^{-1}(I-S)=I.$ (Using (*))

Similarly, $Q^{T}Q=I.$ Hence Q is orthogonal.

Answer (score 0):

I was referred to this question from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3626106/if-s-be-a-skew-hermitian-matrix-then-show-that-1s1-s-1-is-a-unitary), which concerns itself with unitary and skew-hermitian matrices.  We thus assume that $S$ is skew-hermitian, i.e., that

$S^\dagger = -S; \tag 0$

Then the adoint of $(I + S)(I - S)^{-1}$ is given by

$((I + S)(I - S)^{-1})^\dagger = ((I - S)^{-1})^\dagger (I + S)^\dagger$
$= (I - S^\dagger)^{-1}(I + S^\dagger) = (I + S)^{-1}(I - S), \tag 1$

where we have exploited the fact that

$((I - S)^{-1})^\dagger = ((I - S)^\dagger)^{-1}, \tag{1.1}$

which follows from the general formula

$AA^{-1} = I \tag{1.2}$

by taking adjoints:

$(A^{-1})^\dagger A^\dagger = I^\dagger = I, \tag{1.3}$

whence

$(A^{-1})^\dagger = (A^\dagger)^{-1}. \tag{1.4}$

Then

$((I + S)(I - S)^{-1})^\dagger (I + S)(I - S^{-1}) =  (I + S)^{-1}(I - S)(I + S)(I - S)^{-1}$
$= (I + S)^{-1}(I + S)(I - S)(I - S)^{-1} = I, \tag 2$

and

$(I + S)(I - S)^{-1}(I + S)^{-1}(I - S)$
$= (I + S)(I + S)^{-1}(I - S)^{-1}(I - S) = I, \tag 3$

where in (3) we have used the fact that

$(I - S)^{-1}(I + S)^{-1} = (I + S)^{-1}(I - S)^{-1}, \tag 4$

which follows from

$(I + S)(I - S) = (I - S)(I + S) \tag 5$

by taking inverses on both sides.  (2) and (3) together show that $(I + S)(I - S)^{-1}$ is a unitary operator.